# Codigo JS,jquery

Tags: jquery

alguno me podria decir por que no me resalta lo marcado ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("a[href^='http://']").addClass("linkdestacacursos");
    document.getElementById("cursos").addEventListener("click, resaltacursos, false");

});
function resaltacursos(){
    $(".cursos").addClass("linkdestacacursos");
}
```

EL CODIGO COMPLETO:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<style>

.linkdestacacursos{
    background-color:#F00;

}

a{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    font-size:24px;
}
table{
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
}

td{
    border:none;
}

#contieneEnlaces {
    position: absolute;
    left: 31px;
    top: 65px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 649px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top:100px;
}
</style>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-DI6NdAhhFRnO2k51mumYeDShet3I8AKCQf/tf7ARNhI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("a[href^='http://']").addClass("linkdestacacursos");
        document.getElementById("cursos").addEventListener("click, resaltacursos, false");

    });
    function resaltacursos(){
        $(".cursos").addClass("linkdestacacursos");
    }
    </script>



</head>

<body>

<div id="contieneEnlaces">

<a href="http://www.pildorasinformaticas.com" target="_blank" class="cursos">
Píldoras informáticas
</a><br>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="ejemplos">
Google
</a><br>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/pildorasinformaticas" target="_blank" class="cursos">
Píldoras informáticas YouTube
</a><br>

<a href="remover_reemplazar.html" target="_blank" >
Remover y reemplazar
</a><br>

<a href="https://news.google.es/" target="_blank" class="ejemplos">
Noticias google
</a><br>

<a href="calculadora_arcaica.html" target="_blank" >
Calculadora
</a>
</div>

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Cursos destacados&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Cursos" id="cursos"></td>
<td>Información adicional&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Información" id="informacion"></td>
</tr>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: me falto agregar que esto esta todo entre etiquetas <script></script>

Comment: He visto que tienes todo el código en la pregunta, pero no lo has marcado y por eso se ve raro. Lo he editado pero lo tienen que revisar

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué deseas lograr? Puedo entender por tu pregunta que no realiza una asignación de clase. Tal vez si explicaras un poco mejor lo que te propones pudieras recibir alguna respuesta válida. Preguntar no sólo es pegar código y esperar que los demás entiendan todo del mismo. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos

Comment: Deseo lograr que se resalten los elementos < a href> al hacer un evento click en el boton cursos, y el en boton informacion

Answer (score 0):

Te lo muesto sin usar jQuery.
Pongo el script al final del html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<style>

.linkdestacacursos{
    background-color:#F00;

}

a{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    font-size:24px;
}
table{
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
}

td{
    border:none;
}

#contieneEnlaces {
    position: absolute;
    left: 31px;
    top: 65px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 649px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top:100px;
}
</style>





</head>

<body>

<div id="contieneEnlaces">

<a href="http://www.pildorasinformaticas.com" target="_blank" class="cursos">
Píldoras informáticas
</a><br>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="ejemplos">
Google
</a><br>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/pildorasinformaticas" target="_blank" class="cursos">
Píldoras informáticas YouTube
</a><br>

<a href="remover_reemplazar.html" target="_blank" >
Remover y reemplazar
</a><br>

<a href="https://news.google.es/" target="_blank" class="ejemplos">
Noticias google
</a><br>

<a href="calculadora_arcaica.html" target="_blank" >
Calculadora
</a>
</div>

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Cursos destacados&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Cursos" id="cursos"></td>
<td>Información adicional&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button"  value="Información" id="informacion"></td>
</tr>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-DI6NdAhhFRnO2k51mumYeDShet3I8AKCQf/tf7ARNhI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('curso')){
        if(e.target.classList.contains('linkdestacacursos')){
            e.target.classList.add('linkdestacacursos');
        }else{
            e.target.classList.remove('linkdestacacursos');
        }
    }
});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```